# redirect loop and error on trying to setup a careers profile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

started here:
[image]

clicked the "Try Stack Overflow" button and got this:
[image]

clicked 'back' and saw a login with google option (sorry didn't get a screenshot here), clicked it, and got this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. We actually weren't able to repro this on our end and suspect it's been a transient issue. Please let us know if you're still running into this problem.